# More concise RegEx?

Tags: java, c#, html, asp.net, regex

I am using this RegEx in an ASP.NET client-side validator:

```
\d{9}|A\d{8}|a\d{8}
```

And it successfully matches these strings (which is what I want):

```
123456789
a12345678
A12345678
```

*But* right now there is a **somewhat** duplicated section in the RegEx that I don't like `A\d{8}|a\d{8}` -- ***is there a more concise way of doing that?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regex pattern `[aA\d]\d{8}`

Answer (score 2):

Use `\d{9}|[Aa]\d{8}`. `[Aa]` will match either "A" or "a".